# How to inspect the code of Python librairies?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question while studying Python.
I want to check the algorithm of the random module, is there a way to check the code directly?

Comment: It's located in `random.py` in the `lib` folder of your python installation directory.

Answer (score 3):

you can use python to get the source code without going to the internet:

```
import inspect
import random
inspect.getsource(random)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can consult the source code here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/random.py